# IntelliJ SQL Auto-Complete Not Working for DDL

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but whenever I create a new sql file in IntelliJ 2017.1 I can't get auto-complete to show me the right keywords. I have all of the sql plugins installed already. But for some reason it does work when I open up a console directly from the database viewer for a db connection. For example when trying a ddl like this I should get `table` keyword.

[image]

But this does work:

[image]

Comment: From the first screenshot it looks like you are using [Database Navigator plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) I'm not sure how SQL dialect and Data Source are configured for it - you may want to refer to the plugin's documentation.
If you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, and want to use bundled Database support integration, please de-install Database Navigator plugin.

Comment: Then you will be able to associate the file with the SQL dialect (from file context menu) and the Data Source and [run sql script files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/running-sql-script-files.html)

Comment: Thanks. That worked.